# Firebase Make Existing Data Unmodifiable but can write and read new data

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am starting to use Firebase for my new Project which takes in a lot of data. How do I set the rules so that:

- Program can read all data
- Program can write new data
- Program cannot modify or delete existing data

This is what I have:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
    }
  }
}
```

My data is structured like:

```
(name of project) -> users -> (user ID) -> data
```

The problem I have right now is that **every single write is blocked**, regardless if the new data exists or not. What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: First error that I feel is causing the issue is that **you are not granting access to write** your current logic / schema for .write **should be under** `.validate` and in `.write` you should simply grant access according to your needs i.e true for unauthorized access or some authorized access. For better comment on whole rule itself wait for *FrankvP* to have a look.

Comment: The rules look good at first glance. Can you show the code for the write operation that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the user id in your rules. Right now nobody will be able to write after the first user has added his data. To fix this simply add a [wildcard path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) for the user id in your rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".read": true,
      "$userid":{
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Because every user writes under his own node, not directly in the users node. So $userid is a wildcard representing the different user nodes.